# ByteStrings and Strings

Tags: string, haskell, bytestring

How to solve following problem:

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS  (readFile, ByteString, unpack, fromStrict)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8 (pack)
import Data.ByteString.UTF8        (toString)
import Data.Char                   (chr)

stringToBS :: String -> BS.ByteString
stringToBS str = BS.fromStrict $ C8.pack str

recode :: String -> String
recode str = toString $ urlDecode True (stringToBS str)
```

**NOTE** I need to have them the types I set already.

Error at compiling:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
            with actual type ‘ByteString’
NB: ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
      is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
    ‘ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
In the second argument of ‘urlDecode’, namely ‘(stringToBS str)’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘urlDecode True (stringToBS str)’
```

How can I solve this mistake?

Comment: Don't use the lazy variant of `ByteString` for `urlDecode`.

Comment: What is `urlDecode` (type!)?

Comment: where are you getting `urlDecode` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a `urlDecode` in Hackage which fits your usage so I can't be sure., but it probably expects a strict `ByteString` rather than a lazy one, in which case the following should work.

```
import Data.ByteString as BS  (readFile, ByteString, unpack)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8 (pack)
import Data.ByteString.UTF8        (toString)
import Data.Char                   (chr)

recode :: String -> String
recode str = toString $ urlDecode True (C8.pack str)
```